# Changing color of all text on Beamer slide

Tags: beamer

I'd like to change the color of all text on a single slide (not globally), but I've noticed some environments like `itemize` seem to be ignorant to my wishes.  Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textcolor{green}{
this is green
\begin{itemize}
\item Not green but should be green
\end{itemize}
this is also green
\begin{align*}
F = ma
\end{align*}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This looks like

[image: frame]

How can I force all text to a color?

Comment: Green on white background? Really? Beamer uses 'elements' templates.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer why did you delete your answer, I wanted to refer to it :(

Comment: @samcarter: As our beamer expert you don't need a reference to a post by a non-beamer expert ;-)

Comment: @samcarter: No, please. Keep your answer accepted.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I posted my answer as an addition to yours - in the good stackexchange tradition that a question can harbour more then one answer. If I would have known your reaction I certainly would have never posted my answer in the first place, but commented or edited yours. Please undelete your answer, I already included the necessary code for a single page.

Answer (score 8):

In order to change the colour during the presentation, you can basically do the same as [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350577/36296) did for the whole presentation locally within one slide, just with a little trick to use the colour:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
{
\begin{frame}
    \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=green}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=green}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
    this is green
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Not green but should be green
    \end{itemize}
    this is also green
    \begin{align*}
        F = ma
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to a similar version you have provided now. I deleted it. There's no need of keeping two 'identical' solutions!